# How to remove words from a document on a column-by-column basis instead of whole lines in word

Tags: ms-word, formatting, multiple-columns

Perhaps a stupid question but I have a document where I have a large number of numerical values arranged in columns, although not in word's actual column formatting and I want to delete certain columns while leaving one intact. Heres a link to a part of my document.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymTF7.png)

As can be seen there are four columns and I only want to keep the 3rd column but when I select any of this in word, it selects the whole line. Is there a way I can select data in word as a column, rather than as whole lines? If not, can this be done in other word processing programs?

Comment: Download sublime text 3 (for free), copy and paste your data into it, and then you can edit mutiple lines at the same time, this will allow you to select before the 3rd column for every line and use back space to remove the first two columns, see the first answer to this querstion to find out how to edit multiple lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556514/sublime-text-3-how-to-edit-multiple-lines

Answer (score 0):

Generally, spreadsheet apps or subprograms are what you need for deleting and modifying data in column or row format.

Microsoft's spreadsheet equivalent is Excel, part of the Microsoft Office Suite that Word came with. I believe Google Docs has a free spreadsheet tool online as well.

I have not looked at the uploaded file, but if it is small enough, you might be able to paste one row of data at a time into a spreadsheet, and then do your operation on the column data all at once.

There may be other solutions to this problem, but that's a start.

Comment: When I say "subprograms", I mean tools within other programs like Word's table feature, which might provide some immediate options for reformating and then operating on your data.