# Need to deserialize the .toString representation of a complex Map[String, AnyRef] object

Tags: scala, deserialization, data-loss

Due to a bug in my code I ended up serializing complex `Map[String, AnyRef]` objects using `.toString` when what I actually intended was JSON serialization. Now I have strings representing maps of arbitrary levels of nesting.

My goal is to transform these representations into JSON without losing any information or by losing the least amount of information possible.

What approach should I follow to accomplish this?

Comment: Since this is only a temporary fix o recover some data. I would try to paste those string as a literal map in a Scala file and leave the scalac compiler to interpret them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez this is an interesting idea. The toString method doesn't output a string that can be parsed by the compiler. However, if I wrap every value in double quotes, then it might. This could work as a last resort method because it has the downside of automatically losing all type information.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you have in these `String`s. Problem is that `.toString` on its own looses some information:

```
@ Map("test" -> 1).toString
res1: String = "Map(test -> 1)"

@ Map("debug -> 2, test" -> 1).toString
res2: String = "Map(debug -> 2, test -> 1)"

@ Map("debug" -> 2, "test" -> 1).toString
res3: String = "Map(debug -> 2, test -> 1)"
```

How would you figure out if you have case from `res2` or `res3`? In general if any of these `String`s you used as keys contains `,` you will have some problematic case as there either will be ambiguities or syntax errors (if you attempt to parse things).

However, if you didn't have those you can:

- remove initial `Map(` and final `)` using `.substring`
  *`.split` the result using '","' as a separator
- `.map` thw result to `.split` key from value, `trim` both sides
- then the only issue would be parsing the values (`AnyRef`is not very specific).

Alternatively:

- open Sublime Text (or any other editor with [multiline edition support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556514/sublime-text-3-how-to-edit-multiple-lines/39556693))
- paste your code there
- select `->` and use it for multiline select in whole file
- use ctrl+arrows to add `"` around key to make it parsable `String`
- use the same method for adjusting `AnyRef`s if needed
- copy code back into Scala and evaluate

Comment: In the end I decided to use Scala's [FastParse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#FastParse2.2.2) library to parse the strings. Although they are mostly sane, I preferred to use a more robust parsing mechanism to make sure the data is as correct as possible. The only data loss I incurred was in lists containing strings that may have commas in them.